# How to pass some data to onActivityResult() from startIntentSenderForResult()

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass some custom data to `onActivityResult` from `startIntentSenderForResult`.

What I've tried so far is to set some fields via `putExtra` in the Intent passed to the `fillInIntent` parameter of `startIntentSenderForResult`.

How can I access that data from `onActivityResult`? and for that matter how can I start the activity passed in `fillInIntent` from `onActivityResult`?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.putExtra("key", "value")
activity.intent = intent
startIntentSenderForResult(activity,intentSender,0,intent,0,0, 0,null)
```

and in onActivityResult

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
  activity.getIntent.getExtra("key")
}
```

Comment: I dont' think that 3rd-party `Activity` will return same bundle with extras, which was set when starting it...